# Internet related “Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again.” WordPress error

Tags: wordpress

I get the “Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again.” error whenever I try to edit a page and hit update (1 out of 3 times). I tried to deactivate all plugins, set the theme to a default one, etc. but nothing worked.

So I investigated a little further and found out that the problem could be related to my internet connection. It happens when I’m connected to my home router, but not when connected to the internet over my phone’s hotspot (I can work for hours over hotspot without any error but as soon as I switch back to my WiFi, the problem appears right away).

As I use SiteOrigin’s pagebuilder, I [mentioned this issue on their forum](https://siteorigin.com/thread/are-you-sure-you-want-to-do-this-please-try-again/) but they said it was probably a nonce problem.